# Python: converting a list of tuples to dictionary with some conditions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I created a list like this:

```
Book = [(24, '2008-10-30', 'Start'), (24, '2008-12-20', 'End','sold'), 
 (25, '2009-01-01', 'Start'), (25, '2009-11-14', 'End', 'returned'),
 (26, '2010-04-03', 'Start'), (26, '2010-10-11', 'End', 'sold'),...]
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
bookDict = { 24: {'Start': '2008-10-30', 'End': '2008-12-20','reason':'sold'},
  25: {'Start': '2009-01-01', 'End': '2009-11-14','reason':'returned'},
  26: {'Start': '2010-04-03', 'End': '2010-10-11','reason':'sold'},...}
```

For each key in the dictionary which is the first value of tuples in the Book list(it is a code), I want to have two tuples as values of each key. One of them is related to the 'start' point and the other one is related the 'End' point of that specific code.

I have another question as well.
For some of the codes There is more than one 'End' point with different dates. I want to keep only the End point with the later date. some thing like this:

```
Book = [(24, '2008-10-30', 'Start'), (24, '2008-12-20', 'End', 'sold'), 
 (24, '2009-02-04', 'End', 'sold'), (24, '2009-11-25', 'End', 'sold')]
```

For above example dictionary should keep this:

```
bookDict = { 24: {'Start': '2008-10-30', 'End': '2009-11-25','reason':'sold'},
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that satisfies both criterions.

Everytime it encoutners a new book id, it creates a `dict` for it and fills it in as it encounters data in your `list`.

As for multiple *End* entries, your date format allows to use string comparison to get the latest date.

```
books = [(24, '2008-10-30', 'Start'), (24, '2008-12-20', 'End','sold'),
 (25, '2009-01-01', 'Start'), (25, '2009-11-14', 'End', 'returned'),
 (26, '2010-04-03', 'Start'), (26, '2010-10-11', 'End', 'sold'),
 (26, '2011-10-11', 'End', 'returned')] # The latest 'End' entry should be picked

bookDict = {}

for info in books:
    id_ = info[0]
    type_ = info[2]

    book = bookDict.setdefault(id_, {})

    if type_ == 'Start':
        book[type_] = info[1]

    elif type_ == 'End' and info[1] > book.get(type_, ''):
        book[type_] = info[1]
        book['reason'] = info[3]
```

Output:

```
bookDict
# {24: {'Start': '2008-10-30', 'End': '2008-12-20', 'reason': 'sold'},
#  25: {'Start': '2009-01-01', 'End': '2009-11-14', 'reason': 'returned'},
#  26: {'Start': '2010-04-03', 'End': '2010-10-11', 'reason': 'returned'}}
```

Comment: Perfect! Nice and clean! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`, `min`, and `max`:

```
import itertools
def quantity_key(d):
  return list(map(int, d[1].split('-')))

Book = [(24, '2008-10-30', 'Start'), (24, '2008-12-20', 'End','sold'), (25, '2009-01-01', 'Start'), (25, '2009-11-14', 'End', 'returned'), (26, '2010-04-03', 'Start'), (26, '2010-10-11', 'End', 'sold')]
new_books = {a:list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(Book, key=lambda x:x[0])}
final_books = {a:{'Start':min(b, key=quantity_key)[1], 'End':max(b, key=quantity_key)[1], 'reason':max(b, key=quantity_key)[-1]} for a, b in new_books.items()}
```

Output:

```
{24: {'Start': '2008-10-30', 'End': '2008-12-20', 'reason': 'sold'}, 25: {'Start': '2009-01-01', 'End': '2009-11-14', 'reason': 'returned'}, 26: {'Start': '2010-04-03', 'End': '2010-10-11', 'reason': 'sold'}}
```

---

With more than two values for each key:

```
Book = [(24, '2008-10-30', 'Start'), (24, '2008-12-20', 'End', 'sold'), (24, '2009-02-04', 'End', 'sold'), (24, '2009-11-25', 'End', 'sold')]
new_books = {a:list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(Book, key=lambda x:x[0])}
final_books = {a:{'Start':min(b, key=quantity_key)[1], 'End':max(b, key=quantity_key)[1], 'reason':max(b, key=quantity_key)[-1]} for a, b in new_books.items()}
```

Output:

```
{24: {'Start': '2008-10-30', 'End': '2009-11-25', 'reason': 'sold'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for t in Book:
    index, date, marker, *rest = t
    entry = d.setdefault(index, {})
    end_date = entry.get("End", "1900-01-01")
    if marker == "Start" or date > end_date:
        entry[marker] = date
        if rest:
            entry["reason"] = rest[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answers the first part of OP's question only, although it can be adapted for the second.*

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution:

```
book = [(24, '2008-10-30', 'Start'), (24, '2008-12-20', 'End','sold'), 
        (25, '2009-01-01', 'Start'), (25, '2009-11-14', 'End', 'returned'),
        (26, '2010-04-03', 'Start'), (26, '2010-10-11', 'End', 'sold')]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for key, date, *data in book:
    d[key][data[0]] = date
    if len(data) == 2:
        d[key]['reason'] = data[1]
```

---

Alternatively, you can catch `IndexError` instead of testing for tuple length:

```
for key, date, *data in book:
    d[key][data[0]] = date
    try:
        d[key]['reason'] = data[1]
    except IndexError:
        continue
```